# Suddenly started encountering Internal Server Error 500 on Mac for React App with Express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux-saga

In my react app I have an API that I am calling from my redux-saga. I am using express for my server. The code has been hosted and is working just fine. But today, I deleted the build directory and reran  `npm run build` and then `npm start` and started getting this error on my local Mac.

Error on Chrome:

[image: Internal Server Error 500 on Chrome]

The error in index.js expanded if it helps:

[image: index.js error expanded]

Error on Safari:

[image: Internal Server Error 500 on Safari]

I am pretty sure my code is proper as it has been running just fine for months now and I have made no major changes right now expect adding some `console.log` statements.

My API in Express Server:

```
app.get("/api/getProblems", (req, res) => {
  var sheetKey = SECRET_KEY;
  tabletop.init({
    key: sheetKey,
    callback: (sheet) => {
      res.json(sheet);
      console.log("Sent list of problems");
    },
    simpleSheet: true,
  });
});
```

Calling from Saga:

```
function* fetchProblems() {
  const data = yield call(() =>
    fetch("/api/getProblems")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(sheet => sheet)
  );
  //Rest of the logic
}
```

For a brief moment I was seeing the following error:

`Could not proxy request /api/getProblems from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000 (ECONNREFUSED)`

But then it was replaced by the above error.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake in starting the server. I ran `npm start` in the wrong folder. From the root I had to run the following commands:

```
cd client; npm run build; cd ..; npm start;
```